# How to setup project in Visual Studio 2017 for Xamarin.Forms with C++ unmanaged library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-c++, xamarin.forms

My project is targeted at Android and iOS platforms.

I need to create a native C++ library (portable), a C# wrapper library (dll) around the C++ library and finally a Xamarin.Forms demo app using these libraries.
The native and wrapper libraries are deliverables, the demo app is for proof of concept.

I did a full install of Visual Studio 2017, but cannot seem to find the correct combination of project types with all references correctly set.

How should I set this up in Visual Studio 2017?

I don't mind setting up a multitude of projects. My main concern is to share as much code as possible.

Comment: Have you looked into using a C++/CLI project? Sounds like the right tool for the job.

Comment: I read that C++/CLI is not supported for mobile development, so that leaves me with p/invoke. I managed to call native code from a Xamarin.Forms app using p/invoke. The problem I'm having is creating a managed class library that wraps the p/invoke code neatly in a dll. None of the project templates in VS2017 seem to work, or I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: hmm , there is a cross platform C++ project type in visual studio 2015/2017... Not sure what the goal of the wrapper is but this guy has the right idea https://github.com/lothrop/XamarinNative

Comment: @Pat, if you can use COM Interop, there are free tools out there that will create a managed wrapper dll for your `C++` dll. I don't know if the mobile platform will support it, but it's worth a try as it won't take very long to do it. Have a look at [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9776/COM-Interoperability-in-NET-Framework-Part-I) for some basic info. If you think this may work, I can give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your C++ lib (with clang/gcc for example) for each platforms. That shoud give a mylib.so on Android and a mylib.dylib (or mylib.framework if you intend to push it on the App Store). Your C++ should use `extern C` to expose the API. This part isn't related to VS templates/projects, you just need the proper binaries.

Create a .NET standard 2.0 library project. Use multi-targeting bu using `<TargetFrameworks>MonoAndroid8.1;Xamarin.iOS10;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`. Look for crossplatform projects on GitHub if you need examples about setting that up. Your C# code here will use P/Invoke to call C++ and handle the marshalling to expose a C#-friendly API. Again, see wrappers for popular libraries on GitHub.

Then you need to create a Xamarin.Forms project, which contains 3 projects:

- 1 shared assembly with all the shared code and views and references your .NET Standard library project.
- 1 iOS project which references the shared Xamarin.Forms project above and has a native reference of the dylib/framework containing the C++ code.
- 1 Android project which references the shared Xamarin.Forms project above and has a native reference of the .so binary containing your C++ code.